# Customise Brightcove javascript file

Tags: javascript, brightcove

Is there a possibility to customise brightcove js to a minimum size? (It is 669.8 KB)

We want to reduce the size of the javascript file brightcove provides:
https://players.brightcove.net/593354916001/rJtqW9BN_default/index.min.js

by using only what we really need. So we are wondering if it is possible to customise the javascript file just to make the player works without controls, styles etc.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on whether your goal is to simply reduce the file size or to also to remove features you don't need or don't want the user to access?  There are some features you can disable, others you can remove to reduce the overall size, and there are different ways to load the player to improve page load time.

For example, you can [delay loading the player](https://support.brightcove.com/delaying-player-instantiation) by calling the `bc()` method at an appropriate time when your page is loading.

Using the [Player Management API](https://support.brightcove.com/quick-start-player-management), there are several [settings](https://support.brightcove.com/player-configuration-guide) you can disable and remove from the player, however some of these will remove necessary features (`hls` removes the ability to play hls on non-hls compliant browsers and also Flash fallback, `errors` removes the ability to report playback error messages, etc.) so please proceed with caution.

If you need further assistance our support team would be happy to assist you.

Disclaimer: I am employed by Brightcove

Comment: Thank you Michael for your answer. It solved my problem.